# Fire and forget from Google Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have two Google Cloud Functions, FN1 and FN2.

From FN1, I want to fire and forget FN2. That is not wait for FN2's response and terminate FN1's execution.

Will this result in any resource leaks? The reason I am asking is I do see errors in FN1's logs when FN2 fails with a non HTTP 2xx response even though FN1 has been successfully terminated with HTTP 2xx code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From FN1, I want to fire and forget FN2. That is not wait for FN2's
>   response and terminate FN1's execution.

The standard way to do that is to use a [Cloud Pub/Sub triggered Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub).

In FN1, you publish a message to a dedicated Pub/Sub topic, as follows, for example:

```
  const pubSubClient = new PubSub();
  const topicName = 'mytopic';

  const pubSubPayload = {   //If needed you can pass a message to FN2
        foo: "bar",
  }

  const dataBuffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(pubSubPayload));
  await pubSubClient.topic(topicName).publish(dataBuffer);
  //terminate FN1, e.g. return null; or res.send();
```

Then, you define FN2 as follows:

```
exports.fn2 = functions.pubsub.topic('mytopic').onPublish(async (message) => {

    const foo = message.json.foo;  //Get the value passed to FN2

});
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem though is FN2 needs to be accessed over HTTP. Any alternatives?

Comment: What is you exact use case? Can you give more details on the exact sequence of actions and what you want to send back to the front-end?